# Computing $\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, summation

I am trying to compute the following integral by different methods, but I have not been able to come up with the result analytically.

$$\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}dx$$

First I tried something like: $2^{x}=e^{x\ln{2}}\Rightarrow u=x\ln{2} \iff x=\frac{u}{\ln{2}}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\frac{du}{\ln{2}}=dx$.

On the other hand, $1+x^{2}=(x-1)^{2}-2x$

Replacing

$$\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}dx=\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{(x-1)^{2}-2x}{1+e^{x\ln{2}}}dx=\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{(x-1)^{2}-2x}{1-(-e^{x\ln{2}})}dx$$
$$\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}dx=\int_{-2}^{2}((x-1)^{2}-2x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-e^{x\ln{2}})^{n}dx$$
$$\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}dx=\int_{-2}^{2}((x-1)^{2}-2x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}((-1)^{n}e^{nx\ln{2}})dx=\int_{-2}^{2}((x-1)^{2}-2x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{((-1)^{n}n^{n}x^{n}\ln^{n}{2})}{n!}dx$$
$$\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{((-1)^{n}n^{n}\ln^{n}{2})}{n!}\int_{-2}^{2}(1+x^2)x^{n}dx$$

I do not know if the reasoning is correct. I hope someone can help me.

Note: By symmetry the integral can be reduced to $f(-x)=2^{x}f(x)$ so $2I=I+I=\int_{-2}^{2}(1+2^{x})\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}dx=\frac{14}{3}$

Comment: The answer is $14/3.$

Comment: The replacement of $1/(1-u)$ by $\sum u^n$, with $u=-e^{x\ln2}$, is valid only when $|u|\lt1$, which is not the case for all $x$ in the interval $-2\le x\le2$.

Answer (score 6):

My approach:
$$\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x} dx = \int_{-2}^{0}\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}dx + \int_{0}^{2}\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x} dx $$$$ \overset{t = -x}= \int_{0}^{2}\frac{1+t^2}{1+2^{-t}} dt+\int_{0}^{2}\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}dx =  \int_{0}^{2}x^2 + 1 dx =\frac{14}{3}. $$

Comment: How do you do the $x^2+1$ step by symmetry?

Comment: &Tuma using substitution $t = x $ and simplifying.

Comment: @TymaGaidash its $$\frac{2}{(1+2^{-x})(1+2^x)}$$

Comment: @TymaGaidash $$\begin{align}
\phantom{a}&\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^{-x}}+\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}\\
=&2^x\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}+\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}\\
=&(2^x+1)\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}\\
=&1+x^2
\end{align}$$

Comment: @HenryLee ok then. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @TymaGaidash made it fit so added it to that comment

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac{1}{1+2^x}= \frac12 - \frac12 \tanh (\frac x2\ln2)
$,
where the odd function $\tanh(\cdot)$ vanishes under integration. Thus

$$\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}dx= \int_{-2}^{2}\frac12(1+x^2)dx=\frac{14}3
$$

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to put in mind: By a theorem in the book Advanced Calculus Explored:
$$
\int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha}{\frac{f(x)}{1+b^{g(x)}}dx} = \int_{0}^{\alpha}{f(x)dx},\space where  \space f(x)\space must \space be \space an \space even \space function,$$
$$
\space g(x)\space must\space be \space an \space odd\space function,\space and \space b \in \mathbb{R}^+.
$$
This theorem works only for Riemann integrable functions.$$\\$$
So, for this integral since x=y is an odd function, 2 is a real positive number, and the numerator is an even function, we have:
$$\int_{-2}^{2}{\frac{1+x^2}{1+2^x}dx}=\int_{0}^{2}{1+x^2dx} = 2 \space +\space \frac{8}{3}$$
You can find its proof on the internet. If you can't find it, give me a shout.